# In Actionscript, is there a way to create a copy or cached version of a Loader?

Tags: actionscript, flash, loader, movieclip, displayobject

I'm loading an SWF animation and want to display it in multiple places concurrently, but the only way I could figure out how to do that is to load it every time I display it, as seen here:

```
private function playSounds():void {
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        for (var a:Number = 0; a < 16; a++)
        {               
            if (boxes[i][a].x == linePos && boxes[i][a].selected == true && played[i][a] == false)
            {                   
                played[i][a] = true;
                MovieClip();
                var swf:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../assets/glow2.swf")
                var glow:Loader = new Loader()
                glow.load(swf)
                glow.x = boxes[i][a].x - 25*0.7;
                glow.y = boxes[i][a].y - 27*0.7;
                glow.scaleX = 0.7;
                glow.scaleY = 0.7;
                this.addChild(glow);
                glows.push(glow)
                glowTime.push(0)
                var sc:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
                sc = (sounds[i] as Sound).play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is very very slow when it's being displayed more than, say, 5 times at once so I'm wondering if there's a way to only have to load it once and use it in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `content` property of the `Loader`. 
Thus, load once, use the content many times.

edit: you may want to add a listener to know when the loading completes, before you use the loaded content:

```
addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

edit2:

```
var mc1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var mc2:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

var my_Loader:Loader = new Loader();
mc1.addChild(my_Loader);
mc2.addChild(my_Loader);
```

(haven't tried though).

Comment: I tried using content as well, but it still acts as a reference to the loader so if I set a new position then the swf at the old location will disappear.

Comment: maybe you have to **add** the child multiple times. edited the answer for this.

Comment: I think if you add the same object as a child to two different things it is removed from the original parent and placed in the new one. Can't be a child of both.

Answer (score 0):

One quick workaround is to create a second loader and pass the loaded bytes to that via the [loadBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29) method:

```
var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,ready);
l.load(new URLRequest("../assets/glow2.swf"));

function ready(event:Event):void{
    var mc:MovieClip = event.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;

    var clone:Loader = new Loader();
    clone.loadBytes(event.currentTarget.bytes);

    addChild(mc);
    addChild(clone);

    clone.x = 100;
}
```

This will work in most cases. In some cases you should be able to get away with something as simple as:

```
var clone:MovieClip = MovieClip(new mc.constructor());
```

And there is also a 3rd option: 'blitting' your moviclip, which means you'll store one or more (depending how many MoveClip frames you need to cache) of BitmapData objects in memory which will [draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) from the source MovieClip you want to draw (in multiple locations at the same time).

The loadBytes approach achieves what the question suggests: creates a copy of the Loader, so it re-uses the bytes loaded, but initializes new content, so uses memory for that. 
If this is not what you need, caching the MovieClip using BitmapData is your best bet.

Comment: Yeah I got this to work but I can't tell if it's actually improving performance. It still has to load all the bytes, it just gets them from a different place.

Comment: your title suggested you just wanted to reuse loaded content, but it sounds like you want to cache a MovieClip into memory as pixels